# Add associated content not showing after adding new component on the page

Tags: sxa

I have a bug in `Sitecore 9.3 SXA`, where after I added the new component page, the associated content will not show for me or the content editors to add the datasource. I have to manually do that after adding the component. Now, I think the issue is that these components that have this bug, are added additionally to the `site module`. Is there any way to manually make this thing work, without deleting the `site module` and then adding it back to the site?

Comment: Is there a folder under site/data node for datasources of that component?

Comment: @MarekMusielak there is. This component is called features card, so there is a folder features card folder inside the Data folder

Comment: So is it a custom component that is creating the issue, I mean have you cloned this component? Or the issue is with the OOTB SXA component.